# Prove that $C(\mathbb T)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb T)$

Tags: real-analysis

I consider $\mathbb T=\{z \in \mathbb C: |z|=1 \}$ and the space of continuous $2\pi$-periodic functions on $[-\pi,\pi]$.

The idea is prove that $\{f \in C([-\pi,\pi]): f(-\pi)=f(\pi)=0 \}$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb T)$

but I have difficulty to make the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You know that $C([-\pi,\pi])$ is dense in $L^p([-\pi,\pi])$. So, it suffices to show that the set you're considering, call it $\mathscr{F}$, is $\|\cdot\|_p$-dense in $C([-\pi,\pi])$.

Given $f\in C([-\pi,\pi])$, truncate it with straight lines near the end points of the intervals so that it lies in $\mathscr{F}$. Since $f$ is bounded, the truncation can be done so that $\|f-g\|_p$ is small (where $g$ is this truncation).

Let me know if this helps, I can elaborate more if needed.

Fix $f\in C([-\pi,\pi])$, wlog of $f$ is real (else, split into $\Re f$ and $\Im f$). By continuity, $M:=\|f\|_\infty< \infty$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Define $g$ as follows. On $[-\pi, -\pi+\delta]$, $g$ is the unique linear (i.e. of the form $ax+b$) function with $g(-\pi)=0$ and $g(-\pi+\delta)=f(-\pi+\delta)$, where $\delta>0$ is to be specified later. On $[-\pi+\delta,\pi-\delta]$, $g$ agrees with $f$. On $[\pi-\delta,\pi]$, $g$ is the unique linear function with $g(\pi-\delta)=f(\pi-\delta)$ and $g(\pi)=0$. Then
$$
\|f-g\|_p^p=\int_\pi^{-\pi+\delta} |f-g|^p +\int_{\pi-\delta}^\pi |f-g|^p 
$$
Note that $|f-g|\le 2M$ on the intervals $[-\pi,-\pi+\delta]$ and $[\pi-\delta,\pi]$, and this does not depend on $\delta$. So, by choosing $\delta$ small enough, we guarantee that each of the two integrals is smaller than $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more ,please?

Comment: @GiuliaB. See my edit.